# How to get data from related table in 1:N relationship when login in Sequelize?

Tags: authentication, sequelize.js, one-to-many

I have two tables, users and recyclings, which are 1:N relationship (one user have many recyclings, one recycling belongs to one user. When login, I also want to fetch user's recyclings, but it doesn't work when I try to use include. I get response, but without recyclings array.
Response should be like this:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Bernt",
    "surname": "Bjornson",
    "vat": "78965412354",
    "email": "bernt@mail.sv",
    "password": "$2a$08$N02C/YMq0MO.b.eiEZVAc.7cmdb49X1yEPKrFy.8bWU9TsrGgcdfG",
    "createdAt": "2022-08-22T10:04:07.454Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-08-22T10:04:07.454Z",
    "recyclings": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "solvents": 0,
            "acids": 5,
            "createdAt": "2022-08-22T10:04:36.413Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-08-22T10:04:36.413Z",
            "userId": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "solvents": 0.4,
            "acids": 77,
            "createdAt": "2022-08-22T10:05:05.733Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-08-22T10:05:05.733Z",
            "userId": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is login function in AuthController:

```
const db = require("../models");
const config = require("../config/auth.config");
const User = db.user;
const Role = db.role;
const Recycling = db.recyclings;
const Op = db.Sequelize.Op;
var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
var bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

exports.signin = (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
    where: {
      email: req.body.email
    }
  }, {include: ["recyclings"]}) //HERE IS INCLUDE-doesn't work!
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).send({ message: "User not found!" });
      }
      var passwordIsValid = bcrypt.compareSync(
        req.body.password,
        user.password
      );
      if (!passwordIsValid) {
        return res.status(401).send({
          accessToken: null,
          message: "Password not correct!"
        });
      }
      var token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, config.secret, {
        expiresIn: 86400 // 24 hours
      });
      var authorities = [];
      user.getRoles().then(roles => {
        for (let i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
          authorities.push("ROLE_" + roles[i].name.toUpperCase());
        }
        res.status(200).send({
          id: user.id,
          name: user.name,
          surname: user.surname,
          vat: user.vat,
          email: user.email,
          roles: authorities,
          accessToken: token
        });
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
    });
};
```

I don't know how to incorporate getRecyclings() function with existing getRoles(). Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

spelling error,
you import **Recycling** to your code
and use **recyclings** in to your find query include.
change it.and try again